# How do I paging in foreach with react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

Learn the width of the elements to be rendered. If the sum of the width exceeds the width of the device screen, I want to wrap it with an  and return it.

Is there a way I would like to make data dynamic with.

react-native for :

```
getItem() {
    return item.map(item => {
        return (
            <View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: in fact, what I want to do is simply have a total of 50 data item and I want to create a container for every 10 items and paging 10-10-10. I hope to be able to get the width values of each item that I enclose in the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Dimensions } from "react-native";
const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);

   return item.map(item => {
        if(screenWidth>screenHeight){

        return (
            <View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>
        )
       }
    })

      if(screenWidth<screenHeight){
      return .....
      }

}
```